# Find a WebElement on the new page using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tabs

I'm trying to automate a functionality where I have to open a new tab and start to work on this page, but my code still looking the WebElements on the last Tab. I try to switch the tabs with the follow code but its not working.

```
public void DataManager() throws InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(0));
    driver.close();
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
    WebElement tes = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lui-popover-3\"]/div/ng-transclude/ul/li[2]/button[1]/span[2]"));
    tes.click();                                
}
```

What's going on, and how can I fix this?

Comment: don't switch to the first window and close, switch to the second window and start operating on it, and then at the end, close all the window, it would work, that's my guess because it's changing.

Comment: I Switch to the second window, but mycode is not find my WebElement. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had a problem to find Web Elements in my page, so when I used the following code to change the selenium focus:

```
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
```

And I searched the Web Element using press Tab I found it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1st time, You have focus driver on 1st tab which is on 0 index and you have close it. After you close it, Your 1 index become 0 index but you have invoke it on 1 index.

You may Refer sample example:

```
ArrayList<String> tabs= new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
js.executeScript("window.open()");      
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

Here, by this lines New tab will be open by keeping current Tab. And driver will invoke for Tab-1.